# How to return some fields in php fputcsv?

Tags: php, arrays, export-to-csv

```
0 => array[
"id" => "94e568e2-e5ef-4565-b9d1"
"code" => "8899014500001"                                                        
"name" => "John"
"age" => "24" ]
```

I'm trying to convert an array of users into a CSV file. And i set the array of the key that I want to export.

```
 $fields = ['id', 'name'];
```

How can I fputcsv in foreach loop return only user id and name from $fields array ?

```
 foreach ($user as $item) {
      fputcsv($output, $item);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array containing only the fields you want using the `$fields` array to decide what to place in the output

```
$fields = ['id', 'name'];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $out = [];
    foreach ( $fields as $field){
        $out[$field] = $user[$field];
    }
    fputcsv($output, $out);
}
```

Comment: What if $fields can be change to any fields by user and export only fields that user want?

Comment: Ahh i didnt get that from your question, give me a minute to change the answer